# How to push transcript speech to text result to textarea

Tags: javascript, html, speech-to-text

I try to create simple speech to text javascript code, its working.

But when I click the `textarea` and speak again, it won't record what I'm saying.

So basically its working if I'm not clicking `textarea` and will not work after I'm clicking `textarea`.

Here my **.js code**

```
var targ = event.target || event.srcElement;
  var textarea = document.getElementsByClassName("stt").value += targ.textContent || targ.innerText;

  recognition.lang = SpeechLang;
  recognition.interimResults = true;
  recognition.maxAlternatives = 10;
  recognition.continuous = true;

  recognition.onresult = (event) => {
    let interimTranscript = '';
    for (let i = event.resultIndex, len = event.results.length; i < len; i++) {
      let transcript = event.results[i][0].transcript;
      if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
        finalTranscript += transcript;
      } else {
        interimTranscript += transcript;
      }
    }
    textarea = finalTranscript + interimTranscript;
  }
```

my html

```
<textarea class="form-control stt" name="Description[]" rows="3"></textarea>
```

My full code:
https://github.com/jazuly1/stackoverflow/blob/master/speechtotext.php

Comment: so hard to test your issue unless you have to provide full code here.

Comment: heres my full code https://github.com/jazuly1/stackoverflow/blob/master/speechtotext.php